# why does my javascript ignores the second await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

blogCategorie and blog are both CRUD-objects. `blogCatergorie.getAll` gives me all the category objects. I loop through each category and push the name of the category in to an array (categorieTitles). So far so good. In the map function i want to retrieve all the blogs from that category with `blog.getBlogsFromCategory`, but it looks like the compiler ignores the await in front of this promise. It pushes the blogs at the end of the code when i already did the `console.log('Blog containers'). Did i do something wrong?

**Code**

```
let categorieTitles = [];
let blogContainers = [];

await blogCategorie.getAll().then((allCategories) => {
   console.log('after 1st await');
   allCategories.map(async (categorie) => {
      categorieTitles.push(categorie.name);
      await blog.getBlogsFromCategory(categorie.id).then((blogs) => {
         console.log("after 2nd await");
         let blogGroup = [];
         blogs.map((blog) => {
            blogGroup.push(blog);
         });
         blogContainers.push(blogGroup);
      });
   });
});

console.log('Categorie titels', categorieTitles);
console.log('Blog containers', blogContainers);
```

**output**

```
after 1st wait
Categorie titels [ 'Kinderen en psychologie', 'Efficiënt lesgeven' ]
Blog container []
after 2nd await
after 2nd await
```

Comment: `async (categorie)` runs asynchronously! You aren't awaiting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async-await` inside a map do not work.

Also, if you are using await, then ideally you should not use the `.then` syntax, since you can store the response of your asynchronous operation in a variable.

You can change the `map` to a `for-in` loop as below:

```
const allCategories = await blogCategorie.getAll();
console.log('after 1st await');
for (const categories of allCategories) {
   categorieTitles.push(categorie.name);
   const blogs = await blog.getBlogsFromCategory(categorie.id);
   console.log("after 2nd await");
   let blogGroup = [];
   blogs.map((blog) => {
     blogGroup.push(blog);
   });
   blogContainers.push(blogGroup);
};
```

Comment: The await keyword before a promise makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles, and then: If it's an error, the exception is generated — same as if throw error were called at that very place. Otherwise, it returns the result